# UART Software Serial - Syncing two different sensors with start and stop bytes

Tags: uart

I'm using 2 SRF02 sensors on the same Arduino board to attempt to have the transmitter only pulse the 40 KHz wave, while the receiver will be only taking a fake range, i.e. picking up a reading based on another transmission.

I've been using SoftwareSerial and need to know how to synchronize the time for the receiver to know when the transmitter sent the data. What I found is that I'm going to have to do this using start and stop bytes to set them in the same cycle.

How can I do this?

This is my current code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>  
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10,11); // RX, TX 

void SendCmd(unsigned char address,unsigned char cmd) {
  mySerial.write(address);
  //set the address of SRF02(factory default is 0)
  delayMicroseconds(100);
  //serial data is fixed at 9600,N,8,2,so we need some time to create the second stop bit
  mySerial.write(cmd);
  //send the command to SRF02
  delayMicroseconds(100);
  //serial data is fixed at 9600,N,8,2,so we need some time to create the second stop bit
}
void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("SRF02 TEST!");
}

void loop(void) {
  unsigned int reading;
  SendCmd(0x00,0x5C);
  //Transmit 8 cycle 40khz pulse from address 0x00 - transmitter
  delay(70);
  //time for SRF02 to measure the range
  SendCmd(0x02,0x57);
  //Get Fake Range at Address 0x02 - receiver
  delay(10);
  //wait for some time,let the Arduino receive 2 bytes data from the TX pin of SRF02
  if(mySerial.available()>=2) {
    //if two bytes were received
    reading = mySerial.read()<<8;
    //receive high byte (overwrites previous reading) and shift high byte to be high 8 bits
    reading |= mySerial.read();
    // receive low byte as lower 8 bits
    Serial.print(reading);
    // print the reading
    Serial.println("cm");
    //Serial.println("Time Sent: "); 
    //Serial.print(T_sent);
  }
  delay(250);
  // wait a bit since people have to read the output :)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code bit

```
SendCmd(0x00,0x5C);//Transmit 8 cycle 40khz pulse from address 0x00 - transmitter
delay(70);//time for SRF02 to measure the range
SendCmd(0x02,0x57); //Get Fake Range at Address 0x02 - receiver
```

will send a sound burst, delay 70 ms, then start listening for the burst, which by then will have traveled around 24 meters and probably be no longer audible.

You should instead start the fake range listener immediately after sending the burst.  The general idea for one approach is as follows:

- Record time (eg, `t1=micros();`)
- Send burst (eg, `SendCmd(0,0x5C);`)
- Record time (eg, `t2=micros();`)
- Listen for burst (eg, `SendCmd(2,0x58); // Get microseconds`)
- Wait 70 ms, then read microseconds result `t3`
- Compute corrected total microseconds, `tm=t3+t2-t1`
- Convert microseconds to cm

Note use of command 0x58 instead of 0x57 to get microseconds instead of cm.  If you used 0x57, instead of adding `t2-t1` to `t3`, you would add `t2-t1` microseconds-converted-to-cm to a cm reading.

The reason for the computation `tm=t3+t2-t1` is that the second command is issued about `t2-t1` microseconds later than the first command, as explained in the next paragraph.

There is an unknown delay `d1` between when `t1` is recorded and when the first SRF02 acts; and there is an unknown delay `d2` between when `t2` is recorded and when the second SRF02 begins listening.  The correct amount to add to `t3` is `t2+d2-(t1+d1)`, which is `t2-t1` if `d1` equals `d2`, a more-or-less plausible assumption.  If your experiments reveal a constant error, add a small constant offset to compensate.

I doubt you should have the `delayMicroseconds(100);` statements in `SendCmd()`, and would recommend getting the code to work ok, then see if it still works ok when you take them out.  The `delay(10);` is unnecessary if you rewrite your 2-character-wait correctly (ie as a `while` rather than an `if`), and the `delay(70);` is unnecessary if you start conversion with command `0x5A`,  “Fake Ranging Mode - Result in centimeters, automatically Tx range back to controller as soon as ranging is complete” and then properly wait for two characters to arrive, instead of a blind wait followed by a test if they've arrrived.

Comment: unsigned int reading;
      unsigned long t1=micros();
      SendCmd(0, 0x5C);//send pulse with transmitter
      unsigned long t2=micros();
      SendCmd(2, 0x58);//return value in microseconds
 
      delay(70);//time for SRF02 to measure the range //SendCmd(0x02,0x5E);
      unsigned long t3 = SendCmd(2,0x5E);
      unsigned long tm = t3+t2-t1;

Answer (score 0):

```
 unsigned int reading;
  unsigned long t1=micros();
  SendCmd(0, 0x5C);//send pulse with transmitter
  unsigned long t2=micros();
  SendCmd(2, 0x58);//return value in microseconds

  delay(70);//time for SRF02 to measure the range
  //SendCmd(0x02,0x5E);
  unsigned long t3 = SendCmd(2,0x5E);
  unsigned long tm = t3+t2-t1;
```

Hey thanks for the input. When I created t3, I get an error saying void value not ignored as ought to be.

Comment: After you do `SendCmd(2,0x5E);`, you need to read the serial reply from 2nd SRF02, and store that 16-bit value into t3.

Comment: i dont know how to store the value returned, it tells me the the void value not ignored as ought to be. am i not supposed to use t3 = SendCmd(2, 0x5E) to store ?

Comment: SendCmd() doesn't return a non-void value, so you aren't supposed to say `something = SendCmd(...)`.  Instead, just issue the `SendCmd(2, 0x5E)`, then read 2 serial bytes and combine into 16-bit value, like you did for `reading`

Answer (score 0):

This is my updated code based on your suggestions, jwpat, although I did not understand your comment with `delay(70);` not being needed if I start conversion with `(2,0x5A)`.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>  
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10,11); // RX, TX 

void SendCmd(unsigned char address,unsigned char cmd)
{
  mySerial.write(address);//set the address of SRF02(factory default is 0)
  //delayMicroseconds(100);//serial data is fixed at 9600,N,8,2,so we need some time to creat the sencond stop bit
  mySerial.write(cmd);//send the command to SRF02
  //delayMicroseconds(100);//serial data is fixed at 9600,N,8,2,so we need some time to creat the sencond stop bit
}
void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("SRF02 TEST!");
}
void loop(void)
{
  unsigned long t3;
  unsigned long t1=micros();//time tx command issued
  SendCmd(0, 0x5C);//send pulse with transmitter
  unsigned long t2=micros();//time rx command issued
  SendCmd(2, 0x58);//listen for pulse
  //SendCmd(2, 0x5A);
  delay(70);//time for SRF02 to measure the range
  //SendCmd(0x02,0x5E);
  SendCmd(2,0x5E);//Get range






 while(mySerial.available()>=2)//if two bytes were received
  {
    t3 = mySerial.read()<<8;//receive high byte (overwrites previous reading) and shift high byte to be high 8 bits
    t3 |= mySerial.read();// receive low byte as lower 8 bits
    unsigned long Tm = t3 + t2 - t1;//total amt of microseconds between pulse and reading
    unsigned long Dist = (Tm/29); //converting microseconds to cm
    Serial.print(Dist); // print the reading
    Serial.println("cm");
    //Serial.print(tm);
    //Serial.println("ms");

  }
  delay(250); // wait a bit since people have to read the output :)
}
```

After running this code my results keep being the following values regardless of me shifting the distance between the sensors: 
72cm [image]

Comment: Instead of `while(mySerial.available()>=2) { t3 = mySerial.read()<<8; ...` as you have, say  `while(mySerial.available() < 2) {};  t3 = mySerial.read()<<8;`. That is, you need to stall until two characters are available from the 5E command, and then read them.  Probably what's happening now is that first time in, since `mySerial.available()>=2` is false, your `while` doesn't run; so you return from `loop()` and then `loop()` and steps on the ongoing conversion, messing it up; eventually two characters arrive; and this happens over and over the same way.  Note, you should edit this stuff into Q

Comment: I made the changes and what i now get is a value of 2302cm in my Serial Monitor

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question and put current code into it.  2302cm is about the distance one expects for a 70 ms delay.  If you are indeed now using while(mySerial.available() < 2) {}; to stall until 2 chars are available you should be able to remove the 70 ms delay and change from 58 command to 5A command.  (Adding "answers" that are really part of the question is a no-no. Edit the question instead.)

Comment: gotcha, i just dont have enough space for the new code

Comment: also what did you mean by edit into Q?

Comment: I meant, edit the items you've been putting into "answers" into the Question.  By "not enough space for the new code", are you referring to the IDE, the target Arduino, or this post?

Comment: I was talking about the comments for my replies, but i got it thanks a lot for your help. I updated the new code in another question.

Comment: hey I would really appreciate f you can look at my code once more on the new post or even just point me in the right direction. link: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18123/uart-software-serial-syncing-two-sensors-updated